# How to fire "contextmenu' mouseevent in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension and I am using Chrome 26.
I want to fire "contextmenu" event on a specific element in content script.
Here is my code:

```
var evt = this.src.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents');
var RIGHT_CLICK_BUTTON_CODE = 2;
evt.initMouseEvent('contextmenu', true, true, window, 1, 
        x, y, clientX, clientY, false, false, false, false, RIGHT_CLICK_BUTTON_CODE, null);
this.src.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

x, y, clientX, clientY parameters are calculated right after check.
but this code part fails to popup a context menu with no exception thrown.

Comment: You cannot open a contextmenu through JavaScript or the Chrome extension API.

Comment: But this is W3C rules, does Chrome forbid "contextmenu" event fired from js? @RobW

Comment: Most events, in particular keyboard events (think of shortcuts) and click events won't trigger default behaviour. The event is dispatched on the element though, and any `contextmenu` (JavaScript) event listener is triggered.